# App crashing after multiple transition from initial screen to Map Screen which has GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

my app has initial search screen and on search goes to maps screen (`GMSMapView`) in navigation, after multiple to and fro transitions app crashes without error and some times with error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '{id: 31684}: An
>   -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
>       Key path: camera
>       Observed object: ; layer = >
>       Change: {
>           kind = 1;
>           new = "GMSCameraPosition 0x149091040: target:(51.179, -1.826) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:4.000 viewingAngle:0.000";
>       }
>       Context: 0x0'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x183326d8c 0x1824e05ec 0x183326c6c 0x183d39e5c 0x183cb52f8 0x183cb4e30 0x183d39ca0 0x101296d34 0x101294fbc 0x101293fe0
>   0x18d569edc 0x18d6cb628 0x18d6cb360 0x18d569b84 0x18d6cb628
>   0x18d6cb7a0 0x18d6cb360 0x18d568ed4 0x18d39aadc 0x18cfde0f0
>   0x18cf02b90 0x18cf02acc 0x18d2403b4 0x18cfafac8 0x18cfaf720
>   0x18cfa3424 0x18cefb770 0x18749d25c 0x1874a13ec 0x18740daa0
>   0x1874355d0 0x187436450 0x1832ce910 0x1832cc238 0x1832cc884
>   0x1831ecda8 0x1851cf020 0x18d1cd78c 0x100d953a8 0x182c7dfc0)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is my mapView screen code

```
    func createMap()
{
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
    mapView.settings.compassButton = true
    mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake (0,0,0,0)
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.isHidden = true

}
```

Here is `viewWillDisappear` code in `mapview` screen

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidDisappear(true)
    // Remove Advertisemnt
    appDelegate.removeAdsFromViewController(controller: self)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    self.clusterManager.clearItems()
    self.mapView.clear()
}
```